# Recognition of first and last name as one entity

Tags: nlp, tokenize, named-entity-recognition

I am interested in Natural Language processing.
I am wondering if there is a good known algorithm that in a text one can determine first and last name as one entity.

For example If we have this:

`Last week John Wayne went to Europe.`

I want to have a tokenizer that gives: "Last", "Week", John Wayne", "went", "to", "Europe".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is an essential part of named entry recognition and most NER algorithms do it out of the box (most of the time). For example, I ran your sentence through the [Stanford NER system's web interface](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process) and I got:

```
Last week <PERSON>John Wayne</PERSON> went to <LOCATION>Europe</LOCATION>.
```

Depending on what algorithm you use, the output may be formatted differently. The most common format is [IOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Outside_Beginning).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please suggest a few of the NER algorithms that can do this? I am specially interested in none English languages, so I like to know algorithms rather than tools.

Comment: Do you want to know how NER is done in general or do you want a tool that can do NER for you?

Comment: Stanford's NER uses CRF.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how NER is done especially for none English languages.

Answer (score 2):

If the characters in your text are famous people you can do this:

- Run Illinois Wikifier on your text : for example run it on your example : http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/wikify/?id=25
- Combine all the words that are linked to the same webpage by the Wikifier; for example in your example the output becomes like this: 
  "Last week John_Wayne went to Europe." 
  You can also save it where the combinations is done.

Now you can do anything with your text, like giving it to a tokenizer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a good tool, however I am looking for an algorithm to do so. Doing this in English is relatively easier as first and last names both start with capital letters. I am more intrested in algorithms that can be used for other languages.